# How to execute a makefile in a php file

Tags: php

Is there any way to execute a makefile in a php file? I have tried:

> `exec('cmd /c "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\VC98\\Bin\\nmake.exe" -f E:\\dev\\temp.mak > process.out 2> process.err < /dev/null &');`

But I donot think this way makefile gets to run.

Comment: your mixing some linux command line in to that windows one. or visa versa

Comment: I give : "nmake -f Makefile" from cmd to build my stuff.

Comment: Sorry, could you please correct me for the mix? Is it & ?

Answer (score 1):

Try different methods of doing this, Create a windows batch file in the same place as your PHP directory;

```
cd C:\"Program Files"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\VC98\Bin
nmake.exe -f E:\dev\temp.mak > process.out 2> process.err
```

*Incorporating Zids Comment into this: *

*How would you execute it from the command line, if you were not using PHP? – rid*

*If the above method doesn't work. Search online for usage of that exe by running it from windows command prompt, then change the .batch file accordingly.**

Save this as a `.batch` file, then from your PHP try running

```
exec ("filename.bat", $output);
```

then

View the output performed by the exec command in a simple foreach loop

```
foreach ($output AS $OutputStr)
{
echo $OutputStr."<br>";
}
```

There should be some output, from the output I would work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing :

```
$make = escapeshellarg("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Bin\nmake.exe");
$path = escapeshellarg("E:\dev\temp.mak");
exec("start /B {$make} -f {$path} > process.out 2> process.err");
```

- `start /B` will execute your program in background
- `> process.out` will redirect standard output to "process.out" file
- `2> process.err` will redirect error output to "process.err" file

In this example, `process.out` and `process.err` will be erased each time `make` is run. To avoid this behaviour, just replace `>` symbols by `>>`, and files will be appended.

Comment: Thanks, Could you also let me know how I can give the path for the makefile?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I also ask: when I use start /B , it seems running forever, but when I use cmd /c , I got output right away. Thanks again for helping out a beginner. Also, could you also know how I can print out the output on the web instead of my output file?

Comment: Use `$output = array(); exec("start /c {$make} -f {$path}", $output);` instead, and all output will be stored in the `$output` array.